# Filtering the dataframe by matching values of two columns in different rows

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

This is a problem pretty similar to this one [Filtering the dataframe by matching values of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553212/filtering-the-dataframe-by-matching-values-of-two-columns), but I think still different. In the example there it just is required to match the two columns on values for the same row. I am looking to filter a data.table on matching values in two columns, which can be scattered across the whole range of the data.table.

The resulting data.table should look like this, and it should basically filter the rows, which have matching values between `msg_seq_nb` and `orig_msg_seq_nb`. I know that I could achieve that by merging the two data.tables on the two columns, but I thought there must be an easier way, which would prevent the merging and the additional overhead this might create.

```
 dt <- structure(list(cusip_id = c("00208J702", "00208J702", "00208J702", 
                        "00208J702", "010284AH0", "010284AH0", "010284AH0", "U9220JAC4", 
                        "U9220JAC4"), orig_msg_seq_nb = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0003081", NA, "0012889"), msg_seq_nb = c("0008911", "0009000", "0009075","0009152", "0031914", "0003081", "0003105", "0012889", "0017534" )), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame" ))

> dt
    cusip_id orig_msg_seq_nb msg_seq_nb
1: 00208J702            <NA>    0008911
2: 00208J702            <NA>    0009000
3: 00208J702            <NA>    0009075
4: 00208J702            <NA>    0009152
5: 010284AH0            <NA>    0031914
6: 010284AH0            <NA>    0003081
7: 010284AH0         0003081    0003105
8: U9220JAC4            <NA>    0012889
9: U9220JAC4         0012889    0017534
```

The result should look like this

```
    cusip_id orig_msg_seq_nb msg_seq_nb
1: 010284AH0            <NA>    0003081
2: 010284AH0         0003081    0003105
3: U9220JAC4            <NA>    0012889
4: U9220JAC4         0012889    0017534
```

Note that the msg_seq_nb and the orig_msg_seq_nb are not unique in this dataset.

Comment: So for your example above, you would filter out all observations of `cusip_id == 010284AH0`? Maybe add a bigger example along with expected output

Comment: The cusip doesn't matter for the matching to work. The `dt` is basically the desired output, and the initial data.table is just the same but with a lot more entries in the columns, don't know if that would make it easier to get.

Comment: It is better to also give the initial table as well...no need for a lot of entries. just a few more that did not make the filtering

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of:

```
dt[orig_msg_seq_nb %in% msg_seq_nb | msg_seq_nb %in% orig_msg_seq_nb, ]

    cusip_id orig_msg_seq_nb msg_seq_nb
1: 010284AH0              NA    0003081
2: 010284AH0         0003081    0003105
3: U9220JAC4              NA    0012889
4: U9220JAC4         0012889    0017534
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible, since the msg_seq_nb are not unique and it will be much more matches than the correct ones.

Comment: @hannes101 If you look for matching values between `msg_seq_nb` and `orig_msg_seq_nb`, then this behavior is correct. If you want to further reduce the numer of rows, then you need an additional condition. Do you want to filter those rows, where `cusip_id` matches as well?

Comment: I just read that the msg_seq_nb are only unique per trading day, so yes I would need an additional condition. I think I'll just go with a merge between these two tables.

Comment: @hannes101 The example you provided doesn't enable to test this additional condition, so I can only guess, but you can try this: `ids <- dt[orig_msg_seq_nb %in% msg_seq_nb, cusip_id]; dt[orig_msg_seq_nb %in% msg_seq_nb | (msg_seq_nb %in% orig_msg_seq_nb & cusip_id %in% ids), ]`